# How to declare a C Array as a property of an Objective-C object?

Tags: iphone, c, arrays, uikit, nsobject

I'm having trouble declaring a C Array as an Objective-C Property (You know @property, and @synthesize so I can use dot syntax)...Its just a 3 dimensional int array..

Comment: Does your array have a well-known size?  How are you doing it now and what problems are you having?

Comment: It's just a simple 3-dim int array like the one in your answer. I declared it as @property (nonatomic, assign) int myArray[_NUM1][_NUM1][3]; in the .h and @synthesize myArray[_NUM1][_NUM1][3] for the implementation.

Comment: Gotcha.  You can't do that, @property only works with scalar types.  You can use @property (nonatomic, assign) int ***myArray; if you want.  Sounds like a recipe for memory leaks to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't -- arrays are not lvalues in C.  You'll have to declare a pointer property instead and rely on code using the correct arraybounds, or instead use an `NSArray` property.

Example:

```
@interface SomeClass
{
    int width, height, depth;
    int ***array;
}

- (void) initWithWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height withDepth:(int)depth;
- (void) dealloc;

@property(nonatomic, readonly) array;
@end

@implementation SomeClass

@synthesize array;

 - (void) initWithWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height withDepth:(int)depth
{
    self->width  = width;
    self->height = height;
    self->depth  = depth;
    array = malloc(width * sizeof(int **));
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        array[i] = malloc(height * sizeof(int *));
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            array[i][j] = malloc(depth * sizeof(int));
    }
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            free(array[i][j]);
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}

@end
```

Then you can use the `array` property as a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: Correct, but I find it simpler to use a single allocation and then some simple math to access the elements within the array as if it were multi-dimensional.  This tends to be more efficient in terms of memory use (assuming you don't go sparse).